# GUIDrawTexture, image does not resize when I resize the game window

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, resize, unityscript

The title probably makes no sense But I did not know how else to explain it... I can better explain here.

I'm making a 3D game and I have the hud set to the bottom left corner and it will
resize and adjust when I resize the Window/Pick a different resolution, but the Health/thirst bar stays in one area and does not adjust with it and stay on top of the hud...

In example if The hud is in the Bottom left and when I resize and change the resolution the health thirst bar stay one the left side but they go way up in the middle of the screen Hope that makes sense and stuff like that here is my code thanks in advance :)!

```
var hudSize : Vector2 = new Vector2(244, 500);
var size : Vector2 = new Vector2(240, 40);
var thirstSize : Vector2 = new Vector2(244,60);

var healthPos : Vector2 = new Vector2(20, 20);
var healthBarDisplay : float = 1;
var healthBarFull : Texture2D;



var hungerPos : Vector2 = new Vector2(20, 60);
var hungerBarDisplay : float = 1;
var hungerBarFull : Texture2D;

var thirstPos : Vector2 = new Vector2(20, 100);
var thirstBarDisplay : float = 1;
var thirstBarFull : Texture2D;

var healthFallRate : int = 150;
var hungerFallRate : int = 150;
var thirstFallRate : int = 100;

var hudPos : Vector2 = new Vector2(0, 0);
var hudDisplay : Texture2D;

var canJump : boolean = false;
var jumpTimer : float = 0.7;


function Start()
{
onMotor = GetComponent(CharacterController);
controller = GetComponent(CharacterController);
}

//OnScreenDrawing Textures
function OnGUI()
{


GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect (0, Screen.height - 125,244,125), hudDisplay);                  


//HealthBar
GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (healthPos.x, healthPos.y, size.x, size.y));    
GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (0, 0, size.x * healthBarDisplay, size.y));
GUI.DrawTexture(Rect(0, 0, size.x, size.y), healthBarFull);

GUI.EndGroup();
GUI.EndGroup();

//ThirstBar
GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (thirstPos.x, thirstPos.y, size.x, size.y));
GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect (0, 0, thirstSize.x * thirstBarDisplay, thirstSize.y));
GUI.DrawTexture(Rect(0, 0, thirstSize.x, thirstSize.y), thirstBarFull);


GUI.EndGroup();
GUI.EndGroup();


}


function Update()
{

if(hungerBarDisplay <= 100)
{
    healthBarDisplay -= Time.deltaTime / healthFallRate * 2;
    thirstBarDisplay -= Time.deltaTime / thirstFallRate * 5;
}



}
```

Comment: why do people even bother using the old GUI code. Just update to 4.6 and use the new UI system. You dont even have to code anything and it re-sizes itself.

Comment: Because people might be New to the language and NOT know about it? how about that one.

Comment: but its not a language , its just using already made stuff in the editor, no programming involved. If people downloaded the newest version of unity and simply WATCHED a single tutorial on UI there wont be a problem. For example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsZM3q74Q2k

Answer (score 2):

Unity's old `OnGUI` stuff is outdated, and does not scale with screen resolution automatically, short of you increasing font and texture sizes manually.

The newer way to do UI stuff, as of Unity 4.6 and higher, is to use Unity's UI Canvas and related elements.

You can get started by clicking **Create > UI > Image** within the Hierarchy tab, which will create a Canvas and an Image for you.

Check out:

- [Unity Manual: UI](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html)
- [UI Tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui)
- [The New UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui)
- [UI.CanvasScaler](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.CanvasScaler.html) (this is the key component that lets you resize your [UI Canvas](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html) based on screen resolution)
- [UI.Image](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html), and every other class under the UnityEngine.UI API
- [RectTransform](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html)

Answer (score 0):

One Way of resizing the Unity Gui is to use screen specific width and height. For Example in your code

```
GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect (0, Screen.height - 125,244,125), hudDisplay);
```

you can do some thing like this.

```
GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect (0, Screen.height - (Screen.height*0.1f),Screen.width/2.0f,Screen.height/8.0f), hudDisplay);
```

This will make your content resize according to window.